# An exercise where I need to prove that a field extension is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I have problems with this  exercise:

> I need to show that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3})$ is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$.

My idea was to find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}$ and show that any root is in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3})$. The problem is that I cannot find it.

Here are some calculations that I have done:

$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}=a \\ a-\sqrt[3]{3}=\sqrt{2} \\ (a-\sqrt[3]{3})^2=2 \\ a^2-2a\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{3^2}-2=0 \\ a^2-a\sqrt[3]{3}-a\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{3^2}-2=0 \\ a^2-a\sqrt[3]{3} -\sqrt[3]{3}(a-\sqrt[3]{3})-2=0 \\ a^2-a\sqrt[3]{3} -\sqrt[3]{3}\sqrt{2}-2=0 \\a^2-\sqrt[3]{3}(a-\sqrt{2})-2=0 \\a^2-\sqrt[3]{3}(\sqrt[3]{3})-2=0 \\a^2-2=\sqrt[3]{3^2} \\(a^2-2)^3-9=0 \\$

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. Why should the first extension be normal? $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2 + \sqrt[3]{3})$ is most probably equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2, \sqrt[3]{3})$. (Why?) But this is not normal over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I don't think problem 1 is true. Using Sage you can find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}$, which is of degree 6.  Then the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3})$ is the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$. But this field is not normal

Comment: Of course it is not normal - see my comment above.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh sorry, I didn't see your comment, so I just commented for OP to check.

Comment: Yes, no problem. Something went wrong with the question. It is difficult to show a "false" result.

Comment: I apologize, the exercise was to demonstrate whether or not it is normal. I didn't post the same question twice. The second exercise was not present in my first question and therefore I created a new post. I apologize for the confusion. Thank you so much for your help. How could I do the second exercise? @DietrichBurde

Comment: @Tri ? can you also help me?

Comment: and I dont know what Sage is. I can separate $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt[3]{3}$ because they are prime numbers? what if I have a third prime number (like for example $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[4]{5}$)? Can I separate them? @DietrichBurde

Comment: @MarcoDiGiacomo Sage is just some computer package for computing things. I think your second problem also has a typo, it should be $X^2+X-1$ instead of $X_2+X-1$ right?

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion @Tri

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{3}$. Then $3=(a-\sqrt{2})^3$. Expanding everything out you will see that $\sqrt{2}$ can be represented as some rational function in $a$, which indicates the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt[3]{3})$ is the field
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{3})$.

Assume that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt[3]{3})$ is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$, then it must be normal over subfield  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Using the tower rule should give you $$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=3,$$
which show that $x^3-3$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. But only one root of $x^3-3$ lies inside $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt[3]{3})$, which contradicts the normality assumption.